# RESTful API for interacting with IBM DataPower XC10?

Tags: rest, curl, ibm-datapower

It looks like IBM has set up an XML Management Interface for interacting with DataPower appliances that uses SOAP but I'm wondering if there is a way to interact with DataPower XC10 appliances through REST.  Like, is there a RESTful API available for interacting with DataPower XC10 appliances directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can issue JSON commands via the "HTTP command interface" - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS8GR_2.5.0/com.ibm.websphere.datapower.xc.doc/appTaskToInfoCenter_v251.htm?lang=en

For example, to view all users, I issued this curl command:

```
curl -k -u xcadmin:xcadmin -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary  {"task":{"stopOnTaskFailure":"true","command":"ViewAllUsers"}}' https://192.168.56.101/resources/appTaskInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

No RESTful API, but you can certainly use curl with the XML Management interface.